# NodeJS basicAuth

Tags: node.js, lambda, node.js-connect

I want to use basic auth to authenticate users. The problem is when a user needs authentication, the browser loads an ugly form where the user should enter their credentials (such is the default on all browsers when they get a basic auth request).

I would like to know how I can bypass this ugly browser default form and instead serve an alternative good looking custom made form.

Comment: No.  Basic auth = browser prompts.  If you want your own login form, you have to use something other than basic auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the HTTP authentication page put out by your web server. Browsers just pass it as is, and it's not customizable. This is why no one really uses them for much other than locking a site down during development or hiding a particular part of a site.

If you want to do something that fits the look and feel of your site, you're going to need to design a page or include your login somewhere on your existing pages.

Comment: Yup, you are correct. One thing I should point out though: BasicAuth over TLS is great for REST API authentication. But then again, no GUI is needed for REST.

Comment: @Barry Steyn Sure, but you didn't ask about REST. You asked about humans viewing through browsers.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I just wanted to point this out to anyone who reads this so that they get the point why BasicAuth is even useful in today's world. This should take nothing away from your excellent answer (thank you very much for this).